# Flutter background job for access token

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to implement a background job that will run in the background for the access token and refresh token. If the application is closed or not used, will still count the time of the access token and if the user opens the application again to have access if the token is not expired. My access token has 1 hour timer. I hope I explained it good. Thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.

I use flutter_secure_storage to store my access token and refresh token values.

Comment: Okay, great. What did you do so far? Where are you having problems?

Comment: I did everything up to the point I get the access token, refresh token and when it expires and save it. I can use it everywhere and it works fine. Now i want to do what I mentioned above,

Comment: So can you check whether the access token is expired when the user opens the app? If not what is keeping you? What specific problem do you have?